# Проектирование накладной в базе данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных, проектирование

Существует таблица товаров. Для создания накладной в одну таблицу накладной должно входить несколько товаров, при чем за ранее сколько товаров не определено. То есть количество полей заранее для каждого товара я создать не могу. Как спроектировать это в базе данных. В голову ничего не приходит.

Comment: Создаёте 2 таблицы: накладная, накладная_товар. Первая таблица с идентификаторами накладных. Вторая таблица содержит идентификатор накладной и идентификатор товара

Comment: Спасибо, помогло